# Mathematica - using Join-function for a vector in a loop

Tags: loops, join, vector, wolfram-mathematica

I want to combine some vectors in a loop with the Join-function but unfortunately it does not work.

combination 1:

```
i=3;
k=4;
v1 = Range[k]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

Now I want to combine vector v1 3 times (`i=3`) to vector v2:

```
v2 = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}
```

I'm capable to do it manually (`v2 = Join[v1, v1, v1, 1]`)but I need to do this in a loop.

This does not work and I have no idea how to do it the right way:

```
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, Join[v1, v2, 1]]
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Almost the same problem I have with combination 2:

```
v[5] = {1, 3, 5}
v[6] = {7, 9, 11}
v[7] = {13, 15, 17}
```

And I want to combine them with a loop to vector v3:

```
v3 = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}
```

And agian I dont know how to do it because this loop does not work:

```
For[i = 5, i < 8, i++, Join[v[i],1]]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please read the answer about [Assuming that commands will have side effects which they don't](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/731).

Comment: Ok i din't considered this but still `v2 = For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, Join[v1, v1, 1]]` and `v3 = For[i = 5, i < 8, i++, Join[v[i], 1]]` does not work.

Comment: No, why should it? `Join` has no side effect and the value returned by `For` is `Null`. You need to assign the result of `Join` to a variable inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve my problem for combination 1: 
`iz = 5;
k = 4;
v1 = Range[k];
vj[2] = Join[v1, v1, 1];
For[i = 3, i < 1 + iz, i++, vj[i] = Join[vj[i - 1], v1, 1]]
vj[iz]
(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}*)`

Comment: `Join@@ConstantArray[v1,3]`

Comment: and `Join @@ Table[v[i], {i, 5, 7}]` for the second part .  `For` looping is almost never the preferred approach in mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

The most important point has been already discussed in the comments : `Join` does not do specific to the first argument, does not have side effects on its argument.

Also, why systematically using the level parameter (",1" at the end of each use of `Join`) ?

And if you want to do something iterative in Mathematica, why use a `For` loop ?

First example

```
i=3;
k=4;
v1 = Range[k]

Nest[Join[#,v1]&, {}, i]
```

EDIT: *no need for Nest of course*.

```
Join@@Array[v1&, 3]
```

If I take your second example

```
v[5] = {1, 3, 5};
v[6] = {7, 9, 11};
v[7] = {13, 15, 17};

Fold[Join, {}, {v[5], v[6], v[7]}]
```

will do nicely.

```
Fold[Join, {}, Map[ v, Range[5,7]] ]
```

or

```
Fold[Join, {}, Array[ v, 3, 5]]
```

or

```
Fold[Join, {}, Table[ v[i], {i,5,7}]]
```

if you prefer.

EDIT : *no need for* `Fold`

```
Join @@ {v[5], v[6], v[7]}
```

*or any combination of this form with a list of lists generator will do*.

But the use of `Fold` may allow you to do more sophisticated processing.

Comment: these work, but `Join` can perfectly well join a whole list of things at once so no need to do one at a time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should have added this first. I thought it was more pedagogic to make the iteration point. I have edited the answer.